# XML data fetch using Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have to fetch the value of "Grand Total" value from xml , i have written perl script for it  ,but have made some mistake withe the xml tag path for Grand total. Please guide for the correct path.

Below are the XML.

```
<TotalForServiceSummary>
  <GrandTotal><![CDATA[1246.00]]></GrandTotal>
</TotalForServiceSummary>
```

Script:

```
my $salesOrderNumber =s hift @ARGV;
my $billRunID = shift @ARGV;
my $customerNodeID = shift @ARGV;
my $invoiceID = shift @ARGV;
my $billRunDate =shift @ARGV;

my $filename = "So_".$salesOrderNumber."_".$billRunID."_".$customerNodeID."_".$invoiceID."_".$billRunDate;

my $file = `ls /svw/svwsit2b/data/server/invoices/sap_equip_invoice/$filename\*.xml`;

my $return;

open(XML, $file) or die "Cannot open $file for reading: $!\n";

while (my $line = <XML>) {

    if ($line =~ /\<EquipSalesTotalChargeIncTax\>/i) {
        my $xml = new XML::Simple;
        my $ref3 = $xml->XMLin($line);
        $return = $return . $ref3;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the formatting of your code (this included adding the missing closing `}`). You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. If you are asking a group of strangers to read and understand your code, then it is only polite to make that task as easy as possible for them.

Comment: The obvious mistake is that the example input doesn't match what you're looking for in your code

Comment: *"I ... have made some mistake withe the xml tag path for Grand total"* But your code doesn't show any "xml tag path" at all. You will need to show your real code and data to get proper help.

Answer (score 4):

There is quite a lot of misunderstanding going on here.

You don't need to read your XML file a line at a time. You should let `XMLIn()` work on all of your XML at once - in fact you can pass it a filename and it will open the file and read all of the XML from it.

However, you should also note this section from the [XML::Simple documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE):

> **STATUS OF THIS MODULE**
>
> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are
>   available which provide more straightforward and consistent
>   interfaces. In particular, [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) is highly recommended and
>   [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) is an excellent alternative.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options
>   (some of which have unfortunate defaults) and the arbitrary ways in
>   which these options interact - often producing unexpected results.
>
> Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new
>   features are unlikely to be added.

You should seriously consider switching to one of the alternative libraries mentioned above.

Also, these two lines make no sense:

```
my $ref3 = $xml->XMLin($line);
$return = $return . $ref3;
```

`$ref3` will contain a reference (probably to a hash). The string representation of that will look like `HASH(0x12345678)` and that's very unlikely to be what you want.

**Update:** Solving this problem with XML::LibXML looks like this. But I suspect you are oversimplifying your question, so this solution might not work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

# My XML is in "total.xml".
my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('total.xml');

say $doc->findvalue('//TotalForServiceSummary/GrandTotal');
```

**Update 2:** A few other points about your code.

Your lines:

```
my $salesOrderNumber =shift @ARGV;
my $billRunID = shift @ARGV;
```

and so on...

Are better written as:

```
my ($salesOrderNumber, $billRunID, $customerNodeID,
    $invoiceID, $billRunDate) = @ARGV;
```

The `glob()` function is a cross-platform way to get lists of filenames - without using an external program like `ls`.

Please use lexical filehandles and the three-arg version of `open()`.

```
open my $xml_fh, '<', $file
  or die "Can't open $file: $!\n";
```

The "indirect object" way of calling a constructor (`new XML::Simple`) will potentially cause you hard-to-find problems at some point. It's better to use `XML::Simple->new` instead.

Comment: Not sure your first update is entirely correct since the OP code is looking for lines that contain the "EquipSalesTotalChargeIncTax" tag

Comment: @ChrisTurner: Yeah, I based it on the sample data, not the code. That's why I said I think he has oversimplified the problem (and, probably, confused himself in the process).

Comment: Thanks Chris & Dave  for all your suggestions and help and you people  are right , I tried to oversimplified it since the sample  have given is a part of a very large XML file also there are many 'GrandTotal' tags , but I needed to fetch the one comes under <TotalForServiceSummary>.